# Как обновить существующую версию PHP в Linux?

Tags: php, linux

На данный момент установлена версия 5.4.45, нужно обновиться до 5.6, как это сделать? Все что делаю не дает никаких результатов, версии остаются старыми

```
Система: 2.6.32-openvz-042stab111.5-amd64

php5 -v PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2015 09:01:48)
php -v PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2015 09:01:48)
```

Снес php нафиг, попытался установить 5.6 и снова та же версия!!!

Comment: Версия PHP жестко привязана к версии дистрибутива (в целях совместимости - используя ubuntu x.y вы всегда можете быть уверены в том, какие версии пакетов у вас поставятся), используйте [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew)

Answer (score 1):

А Вы пробовали добавить репозиторий с 5.6 и установить новую версию пакета?

Например возмозно использовать вот эту [инструкцию](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/).

После добавления пакета можно проверить доступные обновления и версии пакета командами: `yum list  | grep "php"` или `yum check-update`